# Submit button values not being passed with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax code which submits name/email/message parameters to "messageaction.cfm" template and displays those same 3 parameters on original submission page (works fine):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm() {
            $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'messageaction.cfm', data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
                $('#ContactForm').find('.form_result').html(response);
            }});

            return false;
        }
    </script>

            <form id="ContactForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
                Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br> 
                Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=""><br> 
                Message:<br> <textarea style="width: 200px; height: 100px;" name="message"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="Choice" id="Choice" value="One">
                <input type="submit" name="Choice" id="Choice" value="Two">
                <div class="form_result"></div>
            </form>
```

However, I have 2 submit buttons (corresponding values of "One" and "Two") and would like to be able to detect which one was pressed. In a normal submit form (without ajax), the variable "Choice" is diplayed correctly with the corresponding "One" or "Two" depending on which button I clicked. But in the ajax form, the "Choice" variable only displays the same "0" (default value) regardless of which button I press.

I have tried 2 other ajax form variations but cannot seem to pass the value of the input submit button value. There must be something really basic I'm doing wrong but have tried just about everything I can think of. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since `id` is unique and `name` attribute should be unique in the same `form` as well, you should change:

```
<input type="submit" name="Choice" id="Choice" value="One">
<input type="submit" name="Choice" id="Choice" value="Two">
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" name="ChoiceOne" id="ChoiceOne" value="One">
<input type="submit" name="ChoiceTwo" id="ChoiceTwo" value="Two">
```

and try again with your AJAX code. Make sure you target it properly this time :)

Comment: Felix, 'appreciate the tip but I tried it and still same result. I also removed the second input button so that there was a single button "ChoiceOne", but when I clicked it, it still did not pass back the value "One" but instead still only displayed the default "0". That is what really puzzles me. On a standard form submission, the value "ChoiceOne=One" is displayed but when retrieving it via Ajax, it only displays "ChoiceOne=0" no matter what I try.

Comment: I also tried the following ajax code:

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   $('#ff').form({
    success:function(data){
                    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;
    }
   });
  });
 </script>

 <form id="ff" action="messageaction.cfm" method="Post">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" Name="Choic" id="Choice" Value="One">

Comment: Same problem using the document.getElementById('data').innerHTML. It does not pass back the actual value "One" of the submit button itself.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the `submit` event, jQuery.serialize() does not know which button was clicked, so it is likely skipping those buttons when generating the form data.

You'll have to process the click events for each button as well and manually pass the button value.

An alternative would be to set a hidden form field value when the user clicks a button since a button click event will get processed before the form submit.